# Broadcom wireless driver doesn't work in ubuntu 14.04. My pci id is [14e4:4727] (rev 01)

Tags: wireless, broadcom

Ever since I installed Ubuntu 14.04 the wifi has stopped working. The pci id is :  [14e4:4727] (rev 01). Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer that I am going to provide solved this issue on my machine. It is based on the discussion on this [ubuntuforums page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2232939). The pci id of my wireless driver is [14e4:4727] (rev 01). If this is not the same as on your machine, solution suggested may not work. Below I also describe how to find the pci id of your wifi driver.

1. In the terminal, type:   `lspci -nn -d 14e4:`
2. My machine shows the following : `Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)` . This means that pci id is 14e4:4727, as in the [], along with the revision number, i.e. rec 01.
3. Go to software center >edit>software sources>Additional drivers tab. Select 'do not use the device' under the Broadcom wireless driver.
4. Then go to the terminal and remove 'bcmwl-kernel-source' driver with the following commands: `sudo apt-get autoremove bcmwl-kernel-source`
5. Then,install b43 drivers with the following command: `sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer`
6. Reboot.

Wireless should be up and running.

CAUTION: performing software updates can cause the wifi driver to malfunction again. You will again have to repeat the above steps. So, try installing only those updates which you are sure, will not mess with the wifi driver.

Comment: Does not work, atleast for me. Have the same ID and version on Lenovo B460